# What caveats and hitches about airline seats should a flyer beware of?

Tags: air-travel, airlines

I have long legs and thus for my upcoming flight [to Canada](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/38929/13759), I want to book seats with extra legroom or exit row seats, but thought to Google and fortunately found [this warning regarding Virgin Altantic](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k3675148-Virgin_Atlantic_Economy_Seating-Air_Travel.html):

> > If you pay to have a "legroom seat" (i.e. exit rows) be aware that those seats are more narrow than a regular economy seat. >>
>
> True and not mentioned generally, worth knowing, but again, the same on pretty much any other airline.

So what should a flyer foreknow before booking? What do airlines conceal or misrepresent? Sadly, I'm destitute so am only considering economy class.

Comment: Some seats are near the galley (can be noisy) or toilets? Some seats have the tray table or screen in the arm rest that can reduce seat width? Some seats aren't aligned with a window? That sort of thing?

Comment: Your "to Canada" link seems to be broken.

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks, yes. I especially found useful `Some seats have the tray table or screen in the arm rest that can reduce seat width?`.

Comment: @Flimzy The post was sadly deleted, but I'd appreciate an undeletion.

Comment: Sites like Seat Guru and Seat Plans are pretty good at keeping up to date on all the seats in all the planes of all the airlines, and telling you which ones have smaller width / more  space / near toilets / etc. What are you after beyond what they offer?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thank you profusely! Seat Guru was what I was seeking. I haven't visited Seat Plans yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Promoting some comments to an answer

There are various things you might want to consider for your seat:

- Some seats are near the galley (can be noisy) or toilets
- Some seats have the tray table or screen in the arm rest that can reduce seat width
- Some seats aren't aligned with a window
- Some seats have extra leg room in front of them
- Some seats don't allow you to put baggage on the floor / under the seat in front
- Some seats have extra storage space alongside
- Within a given airline, some planes can have slightly different sized seats to others within the fleet (eg the 777 planes might have different seating to the 319-321s)

The good news is that there are websites that track all this, who can let you compare seats between airlines, and identify good or bad seats + why!

These sites include, but are not limited to, things like Seatguru.com and Seatplans.com. Search around for sites like that, see which one(s) you get on with, then check those.

Also, different things matter to different people, so be sure to read the full details. Someone might say "by the toilet, bad, mark as red", while someone else with bladder problems might decide that that seat is therefore the best on the plane and shout be green!

Comment: "BE GREEN!! By Damn, be green!